# (THEORY QUESTION) If a diode was not placed in a buck convertor, when the switch is off would the load still be powered on?

Tags: power, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck

[image]
**(For Theoretical Purposes and Understanding assume the diode is not in the circuit)**

I just have a bit of confusion regarding the buck convertor when the switch is off. Since an inductor cannot change instantaneously, when the switch is powered off, current will still flow towards the switch. Then a charge will build upon the switch terminal potentially causing a flashover etc (i get this is why we need the diode).

**However as the current is still flowing through the load when off, it will be powered on still right?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The catch diode insures a proper return path for the inductors current. Without the diode there is risk of damage to the MOSFET switch and a greatly reduced output.

There is also a possibility of incorrect polarity at the output, possibly causing damage or drawing excessive current from the source. The diode solves many problems on both the ON and OFF cycle of the MOSFET.

To answer your question,yes, the current would keep flowing from source to load if the MOSFET stayed in an ON state. However Vout would equal Vin with no voltage or current control provided by the SMPS IC.

If the diode is missing, there can be NO current flow if the MOSFET is OFF, as the path has been broken. The capacitor will quickly drain to zero volts.

If the diode is missing and the switch is OFF after being ON, then the stored inductors current will pass through the MOSFET switch, likely destroying it. MOSFET's fail as a short, so it would have to be replaced.

Comment: Would the capacitor not discharge as Well when the switch is open so the load would be on and the current from the inductor would also be flowing

Comment: The capacitor provides very short term power at best. It quickly discharges to zero volts.

Comment: Yeah ok so theoretically for a blink of an eye type speed the load will remain on, Thanks for the help

Comment: Current from the inductor cannot flow if switch is off and diode is missing.

Comment: doesn't the current flow though from the inductor as it outputs a current when the switch is off since an inductor cannot change instantaneously? Therefore the current will go to the switch terminal and build up? However my question was will the load stay on during when the switch is off since the inductor outputs a current does it not?

Comment: You are having a tough time with simple concepts. But yes you are correct. Without the diode any charge in the inductors will force it's way through the MOSFET switch, likely destroying it. This is the primary reason the diode is normally there and never removed. MOSFET's destruct by shorting out, so at that point it would have to be replaced. More comments will have to go to chat.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was confused when in your answer you stated "If the diode is missing, there can be NO current flow if the MOSFET is OFF, as the path has been broken. The capacitor will quickly drain to zero volts." when technically the inductor current will flow unless I assume you were talking about the actual standard power supply current.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Added to answer.

Comment: All good thanks for the help, so just checking basically when the switch is off , the current and charge will build upon the switch terminal and will destroy the switch etc. However, during that time it builds up, the load will remain on? Also as the current discharges from the inductor and builds upon the switch terminal (does it do anything bad to the actual power supply?) or can the power supply handle that external current when it is essentially off?

Comment: You will need to ask those questions as separate post. This post is closed based on your original questions.

Answer (score 1):

As you say the inductor cannot allow current flowing through it, to change instantaneously. When you turn off your switch it is equivalent to raising the series resistance for the switch and hence the inductor in series.

If the current is not to change instantaneously when you change the resistance then the **voltage** will rise across the inductor to achieve the same current.

The inductor equation dI/dt*L=V can be used to *sketch* the implications of hard-switching an inductor. For example dropping 1 ampere in 1 microsecond through a 100uH inductor coil will result in a 100 V spike!

(1A / 1us * 100uH =100V)